# Load rows n to n+x rows of an excel file into a dataframe in python, where n and x are predefined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4500 files, each of them having about 44000 rows, and I have to load all of them one after the other to calculate some values. However, what I am interested are only 20000 rows that start after row 12000. Is there a way to ignore the first 12000 rows, and load only the next 20000 rows?

File mutation is not permitted, so I cannot consider deleting the first 12000 rows from all of those files and use pd.read_csv('File_name.csv', nrows=20000)

```py
df = pd.read_excel("folder_name" + '/{}'.format(file_name),  
                   engine='xlrd', index_col=False)  
df = df[df.Header_1 == 'Common_Value_Shared_By_Interested_Rows']
```

What the above code does is load all 44000 rows of the excel, and then filter according to a column value in Header_1.

But I wish to know if I could do the same without having to load all of it first.

Comment: Use `skiprows` attribute .. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel("folder_name" + '/{}'.format(file_name), engine='xlrd', index_col=False, skiprows=12000, nrows=20000)
```

EDIT: for selecting only `20000 rows` we can use `nrows`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I may bother you a little bit more, could you address the issue of loading only the next 20000 rows after skipping the first few as you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `skiprows` and `skipfooter`:

Docs: [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

You should probably use `usecols` if you know the columns you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I believe @hacker315 answered just as I requested. However, I would keep selecting columns at the very onset in my mind as well.

Comment: It is a better answer, forgot about the `nrows` bit